# Set NoData values to -999 in ArcGIS 10.3

Tags: arcpy, raster, arcgis-10.3, nodata

I know how to set a value to NoData using SetNull, but how about the opposite?

If I had cloud pixels in a Landsat scene that are currently set to NoData and I want to set them to -999 (an extreme value), how do I do that? All the articles I see discuss how to do the opposite.

Any Arcpy or ArcToolbox solutions?  I'm using ArcGIS 10.3.1 and Python 2.7.8

Answer (score 0):

From the ArcGIS help page:
Editing a raster dataset's NoData value
Steps:

```
In the ArcCatalog or the Catalog window, right-click the raster dataset and click Properties.
On the General tab, under Raster Information is the NoData Value. Click the Edit button.

The NoData Editor dialog box is opened.
Click the column next to the band name to edit the NoData Value.
    You must enter a value contained within the dataset.
    Only one value can be entered for each band.
    You can specify a different value for each band.
    Alternatively, you can clear the value entered to remove the NoData value.
CautionCaution:

Be careful not to specify a value that is also valid within the dataset. For example, 0 may be used as a default value for cells that don't have a valid value, but 0 may also be used to define valid values in the raster dataset. If this is the case you may need to define a mask. For more information, see the Mask environment setting or the Mask function.
If you don't know the value to enter, you can click the Compute button and the application will choose the appropriate value.
Click OK to close the dialog boxes.
```

Comment: The reclassify tool requires the new value to be an integer number though. I need three decimal places for the valid values.
I do have the Spatial Analyst toolset.

Comment: See my revised answer above

Comment: No, that didn't work either. :/